# Firebase function not being triggered

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hello I am trying to trigger subcollections in a document here is my code,

```
exports.updateCounter = functions.firestore
  .document('journeys/{journeyId}/{collectionId}/{id}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

      const docRef = change.after.ref;
      const collectionId = context.params.collectionId;
      const eventType = context.eventType;
      const uid = context.auth.uid;
      console.log("Update Counter called!");
      console.log("Event type: "+ eventType);
      console.log("Userid: " + uid); 
});
```

But the function does not seem to get triggered, My database is something like this:

journeys/{id}/comment/{commentid}/like/{likeid}

journeys/{id}/comment/{commentid}/likeshard/{shardId}

When the {shardId} is updated or the {likeid} the function is not triggered

here is my rules

```
match /journeys/{journey} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id;

  match /comment/{document=**}{
    allow read, update, delete, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
```

and when deploying the function:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (41.41 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: uploading functions in project: updateCounter(us-central1)
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function updateCounter(us-central1)...
+  functions[updateCounter(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.

+  Deploy complete!
```

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard path in your Firestore function doesn't exactly match either of the document paths that you're trying to change.  The number of path elements has to be exactly the same.  Your function is looking at documents that have 4 path elements:

```
journeys/{journeyId}/{collectionId}/{id}
```

but your changed documents have 6 path elements:

```
journey/{id}/comment/{commentid}/like/{likeid}
```

You'll have to more specifically call out the subcollections that you're interested in.

Also, I'll note that your function says "journeys", but your changed documents say "journey".  But fixing that still won't help here.

Comment: Oops looks like I made a mistake in the database path

Comment: Hmm, is there a way i can catch all changes in subcollections, doesnt matter how deep, because in a scenario where the comment has a comment and i want to count the likes, i would not be able to capture that. Something like what rules are using (=**)

Comment: Something like what the real time database has: These methods direct your function to handle writes at a certain path within the database instance. Path specifications match all writes that touch a path, including writes that happen anywhere below it. If you set the path for your function as /foo/bar, it matches events at both of these locations:

 /foo/bar
 /foo/bar/baz/really/deep/path

Comment: I don't know, give it a try?

Comment: it looks like using (=**) worked, this is what my path looked like 'journeys/{journeyId}/comment/{document=**}'  could this be added to the documentation. I feel like i might not be the only one who has looked for a feature like this.

Comment: I would still have to play around with it a little to figure out how to get the parent collection name or ref containing the document that is changed.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone wandering i fixed this issue by using this path

```
exports.updateCounter = functions.firestore
.document('journeys/{journeyId}/{collectionId}/{document=**}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

  const docRef = change.after.ref;
  const eventType = context.eventType;
  //const uid = context.auth.uid;
  console.log("Update Counter called!");
  console.log("Event type: "+ eventType);
  console.log("parent collection name: " + docRef.parent.id);
```

});

Every document in the tree will trigger this function. no matter how deep the document is.